# Too many Email Invocations: 11 with List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>

Tags: apex, emailmessage

I have a Schedulable class that I execute every day. I get some accounts that accomplish some conditions and then I create a email for everyone of this records into a List, but I'm getting this error.

```
    public class ALI_AvisoPlazoExcesivoEnExpediente implements Schedulable {
    public void execute (SchedulableContext sc){
        metodo();
    }
    public void metodo(){
        EmailTemplate templateId1 = [select id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where developername = : 'Plazo_Expediente_Excesivo_OMFEF'];
        EmailTemplate templateId2 = [select id, HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where developername = : 'Plazo_Expediente_Excesivo_OPF'];

        List<Account> cuentas = [SELECT Id, Name, desde_fecha__c, desde_fecha_Estado__c, Departamento_pendiente_finalizacion__c, 
                                 Plazo_Estimado_Expediente__c, Plazo_Estimado_Expediente_ESTADO__c, Aviso_Enviado_desde_fecha__c,
                                 Aviso_Enviado_Plazo_Estimado_Exp__c, Responsable_Area_Tecnica__c, Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__c,
                                 Responsable_Area_Tecnica__r.Email, Responsable_Area_Tecnica__r.Name, Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__r.Email, Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__r.Name
                                 FROM Account
                                 WHERE (Plazo_Estimado_Expediente__c > 12 OR desde_fecha_Estado__c like '%flag_red.gif%'
                                 OR Plazo_Estimado_Expediente_ESTADO__c like '%flag_red.gif%')
                                 AND Responsable_Area_Tecnica__c != null AND Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__c != null
                                 AND (Aviso_Enviado_desde_fecha__c = false OR Aviso_Enviado_Plazo_Estimado_Exp__c = false)];

        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for (Account a : cuentas) {
            // Prepare recipients
            Map<Id, String> recipients = new Map<Id, String>();
            recipients.put(a.Responsable_Area_Tecnica__c, a.Responsable_Area_Tecnica__r.Name);
            recipients.put(a.Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__c, a.Delegado_Tecnico_Territorial__r.Name);

            if (a.Plazo_Estimado_Expediente__c > 12 && a.Aviso_Enviado_Plazo_Estimado_Exp__c == false) {
                for (Id key: recipients.keySet()) {
                    String name = recipients.get(key);

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                    email.setTemplateId(templateId1.Id);

                    String baseUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';
                    String subject = '[HEAT] - Plazo estimado superior a 12 meses en el expediente ' + a.Name;
                    String fixed_template = templateId1.HtmlValue.replace('{!Account.Name}', '<a href="'+baseUrl+a.Id+'">'+a.Name+'</a>').
                        replaceAll('<!\\[CDATA\\[','').replaceAll('\\]\\]>','').replace('NOMBRE_PERSONA', name);

                    email.setSubject(subject);
                    email.setHtmlBody(fixed_template);
                    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    email.setTargetObjectId(key);
                    email.setSenderDisplayName('Soporte Aliseda HEAT');


                    allmsg.add(email);

                }

                a.Aviso_Enviado_Plazo_Estimado_Exp__c = true;
            }

            if (a.desde_fecha_Estado__c == '<img src="/img/samples/flag_red.gif" alt="Estado: desde fecha" border="0"/>' && a.Aviso_Enviado_desde_fecha__c == false) {
                for (Id key: recipients.keySet()) {
                    String name = recipients.get(key);

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                    email.setTemplateId(templateId2.Id);

                    String baseUrl = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';
                    String subject = '[HEAT] - En el expediente: ' + a.Name + ' se ha superado el tiempo permitido en el Departamento Pendiente de finalización';
                    String fixed_template = templateId2.HtmlValue.replace('{!Account.Name}', '<a href="'+baseUrl+a.Id+'">'+a.Name+'</a>').
                        replaceAll('<!\\[CDATA\\[','').replaceAll('\\]\\]>','').replace('NOMBRE_PERSONA', name).
                        replace('DEPARTAMENTO_PENDIENTE_DE_FINALIZACION', a.Departamento_pendiente_finalizacion__c);

                    email.setSubject(subject);
                    email.setHtmlBody(fixed_template);
                    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    email.setTargetObjectId(key);
                    email.setSenderDisplayName('Soporte Aliseda HEAT');

                    allmsg.add(email);

                }

                a.Aviso_Enviado_desde_fecha__c = true;
            }

            if (a.Aviso_Enviado_Plazo_Estimado_Exp__c == true || a.Aviso_Enviado_desde_fecha__c == true) {
                accountsToUpdate.add(a);
            }
        }
```

//Calling sendEmail method only once            Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

*There is no email limit from Apex. The limit is on the number of times the sendEmail() method can be invoked from Apex. You need to ensure that you're not calling the sendEmail() method inside a for loop.*

[See More](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324660&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: That's right! Thanks a lot!